# Microsoft Arc mouse on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have ubuntu

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

and bluetooth:

```
hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 74:2F:68:D4:6F:6A  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 121:3
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:8216 acl:0 sco:0 events:267 errors:0
    TX bytes:5769 acl:0 sco:0 commands:125 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0x98 0x7f 0x79 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'kamil-K53SV'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 3.0 (0x5)  Revision: 0x9999
    LMP Version: 3.0 (0x5)  Subversion: 0x9999
    Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)
```

but Ubuntu does not find my mouse in the `Settings` `Bluetooth` tab.
I was trying to hold the `bluetooth` button on the mouse for 5 seconds - but that did not help me find my mouse on my laptop (asus K53SV https://www.asus.com/Laptops/K53SV/specifications/).

Comment: Have you checked existing answers? https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=Microsoft%20Arc%20mouse Some problems were solved in the past like old bluez stack or enabling bt le

Comment: I think my problem is other cause i have bluetooth 3 and this mouse need bluetooth 4.

Comment: Oh I see, it doesn't seem to be backward compatible https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052293/accessories-pair-microsoft-arc-mouse good that you provided a link to your computer model. You'd either need an internal BT4/5 module for your computer (may be difficult to find) or a USB one, which kind of defeats the purpose of using Bluetooth to get rid of dongles. :/